# Map time with RestKit

Tags: json, core-data, sqlite, restkit

I've iOS project which is using RestKit 0.21.0 component responsible to get, parse and store in Core Data responses from remote server. In one of the backend JSON response I have something like that:

```
"response": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "start_time": "10:00:00",
    "end_time": "14:00:00",
    "name": "Object name"
  },
  .
  .
  .
]
```

In *Model.xcdatamodeld* I've defined entity with fields startTime and endTime type of Date. Generally all mappings JSON response to objects works correctly, but I have problem with JSON fields start_time and end_time.

do you have any advices how could be done correctly mapping time fields to data which could be stored in Core Data (SQLite datatbase)?

Answer (score 1):

Create an `NSDateFormatter` with the appropriate format to parse your time strings. Add the date formatter with `[[RKValueTransformer defaultValueTransformer] insertValueTransformer:dateFormatter atIndex:0];`. Now RestKit will search through all your defined date formatters as well as the default ones whenever it needs to map to an `NSDate` destination.

Comment: Wain, thanks for the hint. I've added dateFormatter but now I get strange results. For example string '12:00:00' is store in database as  -24866870400 what is presented in NSLog as 1213-01-01 00:00:00 +0000. So it's not what I expect.

Comment: I know. In I have defined entity filed in Model.xcdatamodeld as Date which is visible in SQLite database schema as column TIMESTAMP.

Comment: Yes, I get that. I'm asking about the date formatter. The stamp should be `1357020000` for that date so something doesn't match up.

Comment: OK, I've set my NSDateFormatter as [timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

Comment: Did you set the locale to `en_US_POSIX`?

Comment: Yes, I have set locale and timezone. [timeFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
    [timeFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];

Comment: I'd look at debugging the mapping where the date formatter is used next to check the data it's processing and the result of the formatter

Comment: I've found that if I don't add timeFormatter (comment line): //[[RKValueTransformer defaultValueTransformer] insertValueTransformer:timeFormatter atIndex:0]; Then I still get the same wrong values. It looks like my timeFormatter isn't used at all by mapping process.

Comment: Adding yours at index:0 should make it take precedence over all of the built in transformers. Try debugging `valueTransformersForTransformingFromClass` in RKValueTransformers.m

Comment: Wain, I've discovered that when I move adding timeFormatter before creating RKEntityMapping *objectMapping (which is using formatter) then everything is ok. Thanks for your hints and support.

Answer (score 1):

Have inherited an app that is making extensive use of RestKit and is at 0.21 release now and its great. Needed to add date to string conversion in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS and followed the advice above to add the required date formatter to the default compound formatters at index 0. However found calls to RKObjectMapping overrode this by adding ISO8601 formatter at index 0 for backward compatibility in +(void)initialize. Commented those lines out and I am getting the correct result. I guess it is possibly the way the app is structured, there are any number of calls to RKObjectMapping and it was not possible to add the date formatter in the right place without the change to RKObjectMapping.